# How to do the navigation while calling webservices in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which

> i want to do pushing and poping of my view controllers to the
>   navigation controller while a webservice call is on

.Now when i am doing it i make all the buttons inactive untill the request finished.But i need to remove this.I need to go back and forth while calling the service.Can anybody help me on this regard

Comment: don't make the buttons inactive while calling the service then?

Comment: I am really unable to get, what you are trying to achieve. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: have you Trying calling webservice in Background using `ASIFormDataRequest'?

Answer (score 1):

From what I get out of your question, solution could be as follow:

You need to implement delegation for this purpose. You have to define a protocol in the class from which your web service is getting invoked. And then implement that protocol into the class to which you want to navigate to. By doing this you will be able to handle the response/error to the navigated ViewController class.

Again, When you want to move back and forth, you again need to implement delegation to the main ViewController, from which your web service is getting called. (Just to handle response/error, in case if you are in the same class while response is returned)

Hope this clears the point.

P.S. My answer is as par the understanding of your question. For detailed answer please elaborate your question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: the problem with this approach will be if he pops a view controller and than the request will have to be reloaded and delegates set to nil.. but nothing wrong in this approach if it suits his requirements.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Yeah Ankit, Also this solution is a bit complex to implement, but as I said, It's according to the question as of now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess.. how about creating a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object which handles all you network related stuff. So instead of calling the web service and implementing its delegate methods in your view controller you assign this object the responsibility of handling the network interaction. This way your view controllers will remain clean (less code) and you can reuse this object anywhere throughout the application... any other thoughts on this are welcome.

Comment: ,thanks for your attention .i need to go back to the main menu before the request is complete.thats what i meant?

Comment: what about GCD,,,like  dispatch_async(backgroundQueue_, ^{
            [self load];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           });
        });

Comment: what If your particular view controller from where you dispatched this thread is no longer in memory..? your thread will continue to run but I am not sure how will you keep track if the service is running and where you will get the data from this to your variables..? I am not exactly sure how you intend to do this, but could be possible.